# IoC/DI Container that supports Compact Framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Is their any IoC controllers available that will work on .NET Compact Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- http://code.google.com/p/compactcontainer/
- http://ninject.org/

Answer (score 4):

[The OpenNETCF IoC framework](http://ioc.codeplex.com) supports the Compact Framework (as a first-class citizen), the full desktop framework, Mono for Android, MonoTouch and Windows Phone.  It's also still active, with updates and fixes still being applied which can't be said about all of the other "CF supporting" frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

[Ninject](http://ninject.org/) is a dependency injection framework that has a compact framework version.

However, in a constrained environment I would avoid using a framework and implement the inversion of control principles in my code instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a new one: [Funq](http://funq.codeplex.com/).
Also check out the [making-of](http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/kzu/archive/2009/02/02/116399.aspx) screencasts.